# List of HTTP methods / new methods or prefixes for application specific uses

Tags: http

Is there somewhere a somewhat official list of all HTTP methods? I found so far a [blog entry](http://annevankesteren.nl/2007/10/http-methods) which points to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616), [RFC 2518](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2518), [RFC 3253](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3253), [RFC 3648](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3648), [RFC 3744](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3744) and the proposed standards [RFC 5789](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5789/), [RFC5323](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5323/). There is also a pointer to [MS WebDAV methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142917.aspx).

What I would be also interested in: is there any commonly used method for creating new methods for application specific purposes? According to [RFC 2774](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2774.txt) there is an experimental approach but I wonder what is usually used for such purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new HTTP spec is going to create an IANA registry for that; see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-latest.html#method.registry and http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-method-registrations-latest.html; for advice on creating new methods, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-latest.html#considerations.for.new.methods.

Comment: Ah interesting. It also points to the experimental RFC  2774: http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2774.txt. I will update the question accordingly.